# How to solve Error : cannot find module "ejs"?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I started a new (and first) **express.js** project using **ejs** but facing to this following error while accessing to the page :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ejs '
Require stack:
- C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\view.js
- C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\index.js
- C:\wamp64\www\myproject\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at new View (C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\wamp64\www\myproject\server.js:10:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\wamp64\www\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

Here is how I proceed from the beginning :

1. Created a new folder called **myproject**
2. Created a new file called **server.js**
3. `node init`
4. Modified **package.json** to add **nodemon**
5. `npm install --save nodemon`
6. `npm install --save express`
7. `npm install --save ejs`

**My file server.js :**

```
var app = require('express')();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send('Accueil');
})
    .get('/album', function(req, res){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.render('album.ejs ', {name :'yop'});
    })
    .use(function(req, res, next){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !');
    });

app.listen(8080);
```

**My file package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

**My project's structure :**

```
My project directory
   node_modules folder
   views folder
      album.ejs file
   package.json
   server.js
```

Comment: Do you also have Express installed globally?

Comment: I tried with express also installed globally doing "npm install -g express" and I still have the same error.

Comment: No, I meant you should do exactly the opposite. If you have a global express installation, it might cause problems with ejs. Add the album.ejs code, please.

Comment: Initially I just had only what I detailed in my post, so just express installed locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add one extra space accidentally behind the ejs.

```
res.render('album.ejs ', {name :'yop'});
```

Remove that space like below.

```
res.render('album.ejs', {name :'yop'});
```

And you could just use the file name without extension name.

```
res.render('album', {name :'yop'});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That space ((and myself of course!) was the cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

in your **server.js**

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me but It doesn't solve the error If I add this line.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code just below `app.set('view engine', 'ejs)`

```
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already had installed ejs, you must uninstall and install it again
Here are the steps:

1. `npm uninstall ejs --save`
2. `npm install ejs --save`